# Library or component for creating video files (AVI, etc.) with Delphi 6 (C/C++ OK too)?

Tags: delphi, video, codec, avi, vfw

I have a stream of JPEG frames and accompanying audio buffers that I want to write to a video file.  If possible, I'd like to let the user choose their format from the available Windows codecs if the library/component supports the use of those.  If not, then if it can create something popular like AVI, WMV, or MOV format files then that would be fine.  Does anyone know of a good library or component compatible with Delphi 6 that can do this?  If not, a C/C++ sample would work too.

Comment: Why the downvote?  Seems a reasonable question to me!

Comment: Any success with this? Have you decided which library to use?

Comment: @SolarWind No.  Gave up and moved on to another project.

Comment: @RobertOschler-Thanks for your quick answer. It is sad that Delphi lags so much behind when about multimedia.

Answer (score 2):

For AVI you may want to check if you have access to the AVIFile APIs from Delphi. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770078/getting-avi-file-duration) suggests it is possible.

For WMV look for DirectShow access.

For MOV you can use the free Quicktime SDK.

It appears the [JEDI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/) site might have some API bindings that you can use.

Comment: Delphi does not come with header translations for the VFW functions in avifil32, but there are translations available and it's pretty trivial to translate what you need yourself.